# How to count all users with a specific role in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identity

I am working on a Asp.net core 2.0 project with Identity. My project created and develop with core 1.1 and after a while migrate to core 2.0. 
After migration to core 2.0 all thing is good, but in part of the project i need to get all user with a specific role. 
In Asp.Net Core 1.1 I get the count of all specific role with this code:

```
r.Users.Count
```

completed code :

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ApplicationRoleViewModel> model = new List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>();
        model = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleViewModel
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
        }).ToList();

        return View(model);

    }
```

and :

```
public class ApplicationRoleViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfUsers { get; set; }
}
```

But there is not the `Users` object in core 2.0.
also i see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384698/get-all-users-with-a-specific-role-in-asp-net-core-2-0) but i can not solve my problem.
Now how can i count all users with a specific role in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UserRoles` collection stores all references between users and which roles they are a part of. You can do something like this:

```
var allUserRoles = _identityDb.UserRoles.ToList();
model = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleViewModel
{
    Id = r.Id,
    Name = r.Name,
    Description = r.Description,
    NumberOfUsers = allUserRoles.Count(ur => ur.RoleId == r.Id)
}).ToList();
```

Keep in mind this is pretty inefficient as it does the counting in your action and not on the database. Ideally this would be done directly by the generated sql query but if you aren't dealing with a large quantity of users / roles this naive solution should work just fine.

---

If you already have a custom `IdentityRole` and `UserRole` model you should be able to add properties that will allow you to use IdentityDb.Roles.Include() to reference the UserRoles based on RoleId. Alternatively, you could use a query similar to below to execute a custom sql command which would return the desired information. Keep in mind the columns or tables of your identity database may differ here.

```
List<ApplicationRoleViewModel> vm = new List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>();

using (var dbConnection = _identityDb.Database.GetDbConnection())
using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCommand.CommandText =
        @"SELECT 
            r.Id,
            r.Name,
            r.Description
            Count(ur.UserId)  as NumberOfUsers
        FROM AspNetRoles r
        FULL OUTER JOIN AspNetUserRoles ur ON r.Id = ur.RoleId
        GROUP BY r.Id, r.Name, r.Description";

    dbConnection.OpenAsync().Wait();
    using (var result = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (result.Read())
        {
            vm.Add(new ApplicationRoleViewModel()
            {
                Id = result.GetString(0),
                Name = result.GetString(1),
                Description = result.GetString(2),
                NumberOfUsers = result.GetInt32(3)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain a little about the better method or introduce a link?

Comment: Can't you simply fetch the desired `Role` and then do something like `await _context.UserRoles.CountAsync(ur => ur.RoleId == theRoleImLookingFor.Id);`

Answer (score 1):

You can have UserManager and RoleManager injected in to your controller if asp.net identity is properly configured.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userMgr,
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleMgr) 
    {
      userManager = userMgr;
      roleManager = roleMgr;
    }
}
```

Now , you can invoke GetUsersInRoleAsync("myRole") on userManager to get all the users in myRole in your action methods.